# Combining Print Statements in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C, and I am running into some problems which make me write (seemingly) redundant code. I am finding myself writing code like

```
printf("%c", someChar);
printf(" ");
```

which (since it is in a loop) would output something like

```
a b c
```

Is there any way to combine these print statements?

Comment: `printf("%c ", someChar);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just write : `printf("%c ", someChar);`

note the space after `%c`

Answer (score 3):

Every character except the **first** character output in the loop needs a leading space.

```
for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
{
     char c = get_next_char();
     printf("%s%c", (x==0) ? "" : " ", c); // if (x == 0) then print "%c" else print " %c"
}
```

Comment: Can you give an explanation for that formatting (Not the logic, just what you did with that %s%c)

Comment: `%s` is "string" and `%c` as you know is "char".  This expression `(x==0) ? "" : " "` says "if x is 0, then insert an empty string for `%s` otherwise insert a string with exactly one space for `%s`.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place a space after `%c` in this case

```
printf("%c ", someChar);
```

In some other cases you can format output using single printf statement (to reduce printf statements as you say) by using escpae sequences,
try these within "", like,

```
printf("%c\n", someChar);
```

`\n` places a new line

Some others are `\t`, `\\` and `\"`.